# How do you get Typescript auto-indenting in VSCode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a project in Typescript using VS Code.

When I try to autoindent, I get a little dropdown asking me if it's JS, CSS or HTML. However, in the bottom corner of window, VS Code clearly indicates that it knows I'm coding Typescript.

When I select Javascript, the problem is that it indents a lot of things in a funny, non-Typescript way, for example it turns this

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction, Router } from "express";
```

into this

```
import {
  Request,
  Response,
  NextFunction,
  Router
} from "express";
```

How can I get auto-indent to work for Typescript?

Comment: Typescript is a superset of Javascript. Pick javascript :)

Comment: @MolikMiah see my update. I show why Javascript indenting is bad

Comment: This behavior is coming from one of your extensions. Try looking through them to track down which one is causing this. Prettier or jsbeautify have caused problems like this in the past for example